# F#Data HTML Type provider missing Table types

Tags: f#, f#-data, f#-3.0

The documentation at

http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlProvider.html

claims the following;

"The generated type provides a type space of tables that it has managed to parse out of the given HTML Document. Each type's name is derived from either the id, title, name, summary or caption attributes/tags provided. If none of these entities exist then the table will simply be named Tablexx where xx is the position in the HTML document if all of the tables were flatterned out into a list. "

I am trying to parse the following url
optionsdata = = HtmlProvider<"http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=DDD+Options">

I do not see any Tablexx... types.  Any help is appreciated and Thanks in advance.  When I view source there are /table tags and there certainly are tables on the html page.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Yahoo does not send you the page with the same content that you can see in a web browser when you make a plain `GET` request from a script. This is why the type provider cannot see the tables - they are actually missing in the HTML that gets to the type provider. You can see this by looking at the `Html` that the type provider gets when you load the page using it:

```
type DDD = HtmlProvider<"http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=DDD+Options">
DDD.GetSample().Html |> printfn "%A"
```

As a fix, you can view the source code in a browser, save it in a local file and then pass that to the type provider. Using this, I was able to write the following code:

```
type DDD = HtmlProvider<"c:/temp/yahoo.html">
let ddd = DDD.GetSample()

for r in ddd.Tables.Table1.Rows do
  printfn "%s" r.``Contract Name``
```

The `GetSample` method just loads the file from the file system. I assume you want to parse live web pages - for that, you'll need to figure out how the get the right HTML from Yahoo (presumably, by setting some HTTP headers and cookies). Then you can call `DDD.Parse(html)` to load your actual data.